# Issue with nested templated classes

Tags: c++, templates, types, constructor, inner-classes

I am trying to create a simple stack using templated classes. There seems to be an issue when one class calls the constructor of the other class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int g_MaxSize = 100;
template <class T>
class Stack;

template <class D>
class Node
{
private:
    D data;
public:
    Node(D value): data(value)
    {
    }
    template <class T>
    friend class Stack;
};

template <class T>
class Stack
{
private:
    std::vector<Node<T>> stack;
    int top;
public:
    Stack(): stack(g_MaxSize), top(0)
    {
    }

    void push(T val)
    {
        // make sure stack isnt full

        stack[top++]= Node<T>(val);
    }

    Node<T> pop()
    {
        return stack[top--];
    }

    Node<T> peek()
    {
        return stack[top];
    }
};

int  main() {

    Node<int> testNode(1) // *this works*
    Stack<int> myStack;
    myStack.push(3);

    return 0;
}
```

The error is " No matching constructor for initialization of 'Node' ". As shown in the code above, Node constructor works on its own but it does not work when done through the Stack class.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of `Node` in this at all. Why not just store  `T` in your vector?.

Comment: Yeah. I was just doing a baseline example but I thought it would be best to do it this way so that its easy to extend Node when I want more functionality for each Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue here is that `stack(g_MaxSize)` in `Stack(): stack(g_MaxSize), top(0)`
is requesting that you construct `g_MaxSize` default constructed `Node`s in the vector.  You can't do that though since `Node` is not default constructable.

You can add a default constructor to `Node` that will fix that.  Another way would be to pass a default `Node` to the vector constructor like `stack(g_MaxSize, Node<T>(1))`. Lastly you could create the vector with zero size and then call `reserve` in the constructor body to allocate the storage for the `Node`s without constructing them.

Comment: Thank you! Any suggestions about when it would be best to use `reserve` ?

Comment: @ascar I would only use it if you want to defer construction of the objects in the vector until you know what they will be.

Answer (score 1):

The argument of `vector` needs a default constructor. `Node` is missing one, hence the error.

Comment: Thank for the quick answer!